# Вывести самое длинное слово в предложении

Tags: php

Дана строка-предложение на русском языке. Вывести самое длинное
слово в предложении. Если таких слов несколько, то вывести первое из
них. Словом считать набор символов, не содержащий пробелов, знаков
препинания и ограниченный пробелами, знаками препинания или началом/концом строки.

Comment: Как решить задачу, путем использования уже готовых для работы с массивом строк методы в php?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что согласно правилам сообщества вопрос не должен сводиться к решению учебных заданий за учащегося.

Answer (score 1):

Функцией `explode` получишь массив слов в предложении,а дальше уже высчитываешь длину каждого слова,можно через `strlen`

Comment: еще нужно избавиться от знаков препинания!)

Comment: тогда перефразирую: как из предложения "привет, меня зовут Алакай!" - вытащить { "привет,", "меня,", "зовут", "Алакай". }

Comment: Можно сперва replace запятых на пробелы,а дальше как я описал выше)

Answer (score 1):

Для любителей функционального подхода:

```
$input = 'Fooo bar bazzz, фыва-олдж.';

$longest = array_reduce(preg_split('/[^a-zа-яё]+/ui', $input), function ($longest, $curr) {
    return mb_strlen($longest) < mb_strlen($curr)
        ? $curr
        : $longest; 
}, '');

echo($longest); // "bazzz"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$words = explode(" ", preg_replace("/[^A-ZА-ЯЁ ]/ui", " ", $str));
$long = "";
foreach ($words as $word)
  $long = (mb_strlen($word) > mb_strlen($long)) ? $word : $long;
echo $long;
```

Comment: Диапазон символов `A-Z`(как, впрочем, и `А-ЯЁ`) в регулярном выражении избыточен, т.к. указан флаг регистронезависимости.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, спасибо