# Как максимально функционально разбить предложение на массив

Tags: php

Как максимально функционально разбить предложение, разделенное N-пробелами и знаками препинания на массив слов?

```
$array = explode(" ",  preg_replace('|\s+|', ' ',
        str_replace(array(".", "?", "!", "...", ";", ",", "-"), "", $string)));
```

Этот вариант - просто жесть, но работает.
Сначала получаю исходное предложение без знаков препинания, потом заменяю все пробелы - на один пробел. А потом получаю массив слов, через explode с разделителем пробел.
Как можно сделать покрасивше? =3

Comment: то есть хотите сказать, что в данном варианте нет путаницы между `.` и `...`? или если встречается прямая речь - то отрабатывает корректно? или инициалы, например `М. Ю. Лермонтов?`

Comment: как тогда такое обойти?

Comment: @Kryshtop, ответы на [другие свои вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/601555/182771) принципиально не читаете? `preg_split('/[^a-zа-яё]+/ui', $input)`, не?